# iPhone localstorage lifecycle - does it survive an app-update?

Tags: iphone, html, app-store, local-storage

I'm currently developing an iPhone App that uses Phonegap and HTML5. I use localstorage to save in-game-achievements.

I was wondering what would happen the user pulls an update for that app from the AppStore. Is the localstorage data persistent? Or do I have to switch to SQLite, which is actually abandoned by the W3C..

Any experience would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8947933/165674).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes your localStorage is going to stick around until the app is deleted.

Try it out by building a basic app that you set some localStorage items, then recompile and update the app with changes your localStorage will stay where it is.

SQLLite will work, but you can store quite a bit of information in localStorage and achieve nearly the same results.

I use localStorage in a number of projects and it works great!

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Note: in iOS 5.1, the location of web storage (like sqlite/localStorage) has changed to be resident in the Library/Caches directory. Which means it is /very/ vulnerable and apt to disappear.

Comment: Very good call Kerri, speaking of your solution works very well - here's the code http://pastebin.com/5881768B and follow the conversation here - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/RJC2qA9sDnw

Answer (score 0):

If for `localstorage` you mean `NSLibraryDirectory` or `NSDocumentDirectory` your data should be available even after an upgrade.

Comment: I mean html5 localstorage in browsers [like here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)

Comment: Well, it seems I have misunderstood your question... Sorry.